# How to change signature of PNG file to "uncorrupt?"

Tags: png, corrupt

So I have a corrupted PNG file (that I don't want to convert to JPG, etc. It has to be basically the same.) and I checked its first eight bytes (signature):

`8950 4e47 0d0a b0aa`

The actual signature for a PNG file is:

`8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a`

How can I change the signature of my corrupted file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hexedit you can manipulate your files. For that simply follow these steps:

1. Install hexedit
2. Open your file in hexedit
3. Move the cursor over a byte (here you have to move over the corrupted byte)
4. Enter what you would like to change the byte
5. Save the file

**Update**

To install hexedit run following command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install hexedit
```

For more info take a look at [this blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-magic-numbers-in-linux/).

Comment: I actually just got hex fiend and that seems to be working fine so yay!